# Change the geometry type from LineString to MultiLineString SQL Server

Tags: sql, geometry, sql-server, linestring

I have a SQL Server database table to contains two geometry types: LineString; and, MultiLineString.

What is the best way to change the type of all of the LineString geometries to 1 part MultiLineString geometries?

I have tried:

`UPDATE Footpaths
SET Geom.STGeometryType() = 'MultiLineString';`

Comment: No, that's a read-only property. You need to reload the geometry as a singleton multipart.

Comment: This is for an original data set, so, reloading is not an option.

Comment: You certainly can't change a geometry by putting a function on the left side of an assignment statement. UPDATEs fragment tables; far better to do an initial load to a staging table, then conditionally INSERT into a final table. So, not only is reloading an option, it's actually best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I found was to set the geometry from text after reading the geometry as a text string and reformatting it:

`UPDATE [GIS].[dbo].[Footpaths]
SET [Geom] = geometry::STGeomFromText(CONCAT(REPLACE([Geom].STAsText(),'LINESTRING ', 'MULTILINESTRING ('),')'),28356)
WHERE [Geom].STGeometryType() = 'LineString'`